# ant replaceregexp task: replace with exact length

Tags: ant

I select a part of a sentence with a regex expression.
I will use that selected part as \1 in the replace-part of the replaceregexp task.
But I want that this selected part will be transformed to 20 positions.

How can I do this??

Example (not my real case but a very simpel example) – I have the following text:

```
Def var iThisVariable as int.
```

I use the following:

```
<replaceregexp file="${NMfile}" flags="ig" match="def var (\S+) as int\." replace="def var \1 as int\."/>
```

But I want that the `\1` that holds the value `"iThisVariable"` is here 20 positions long so `"iThisVariable       "`

Someone knows how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `(\S+)` matches one or more non-whitespace characters. If you wanted to match the spaces as well you could use `(.+)` but then you'd just end up with the original string. What are you trying to actually change in this file? Are you trying to remove line breaks?

Comment: No, I want to align my coding.
Because I do not have a constant width for my variable-names I want to replace all variable-names to 20 positions.

So when I have:
def var iSmall as int.
def var iThisIsLarger as int.

I want it to become:
def var iSmall              as int.
def var iThisIsLarger       as int

Maybe ANT is not really made for this but when I run my ANT-script to do some other replacements I can also try to do this in the same script.
That way I only need to run 1 script for all things that i want to do.

Comment: mhhh, it looks like when I add comment is is not formatted like i intent to be ... and I do not understand how I can format it correctly (even after looking at the Markdown page).
Can someone tell me how I can format my comment so I can make the problem clear?

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Unfortunately, determining the number of spaces to add to each variable name will require some math, which native Ant and regex aren't really capable of. Even with ant-contrib's math task this would be quite difficult and byzantine, if not impossible. If you really need to do this as part of your Ant build, I would recommend using the `<script>` task, with your programming language of choice.